# Cell change not triggering VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am trying to use the following VBA macro to alter the content of a cell when a particular character is entered into it.

```
Sub replaceWords()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim r As Integer

        For i = 1 To 60
            For r = 1 To 60
                If Cells(i, r).Value = "`" Then
                Cells(i, r).Value = "0,0"
                End If
            Next r
        Next i
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("A1:AA100")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Call replaceWords
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

My understanding is that `Worksheet_Change` should do this automatically, but it doesn't seem to be working - I have to run the macro manually. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the `worksheet_change` module going in the workseet object?

Comment: Is this on a Macintosh or did you accidentally mistake the `macros` flag for the `macos` flag?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your code, but make sure `Worksheet_Change` is in the `Worksheet` object by going to the Project Explorer (Ctrl-R) and right click on the worksheet in question and select View Code. Put that `worksheet_change` module in there.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the function is in the worksheet's module. If that still doesn't work, check to see if `Application.EnableEvents` is set to `True`.

You set that value to false as your code makes changes. If your code was interrupted before resetting it to True, the event driven subs won't fire.

Adding some error handling where you exit gracefully and reset EnableEvents to True is generally a good idea.